# Replace String with Shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to replace a string from shell. I have already read the string and it's in template variable. Now I am trying to replace the `companyId` which store in `REPLACE_COMPANY` variable  with the parameter passed in shell. I have tried few solution from net but didn't succeeded. Also I want to keep the file format intact as with replace I found all string comes into one line. Can anyone help.

```
REPLACE_COMPANY="companyId" 
echo "$template" 
##### Company: companyId CONFIG  START #####

backend FE:spaces-companyId
        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
        balance roundrobin
        server 1-www spacesIp:80 check cookie s2

backend BE:synapse-companyId
         redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
         balance roundrobin
         server 1-www synapseIp:8008 check cookie s2

##### Company: companyId CONFIG  END #####
```

Comment: It is confusing. Do you just need `sed -i "/companyld/\$template/ filename` so you end up with `REPLACE_COMPANY="$template"` ? Is that your goal?

Comment: can you provide expected result ?

Comment: Hi Expected goad is, all the text (avaiable in $template) where companyId(Declared in $REPLACE_COMPANY) is mentioned will be replaced with the parameter I passed in $1 of shell and will be stored in a variable again. Also the formatting will remain same.I don't want to write it directly to any file first as other works needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `envsubst` to replace variable references in files with the values available in the current shell. For example:

```
$ cat test.template
Hi $USER
$ envsubst < test.template
Hi username
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done from my side. Please find the code below. Thanks for all the helps.

**Note:** INF contains the file name which contains the template which needs to be modifies and write back. and $FILE contains where the final output need to be written.

```
provision(){
   INF="proxy.template"
   REPLACE_COMPANY="companyId"
   REPLACE_SPACEIP="spacesIp"
   REPLACE_SYNAPSEIP="synapseIp"
   sed -e "s/$REPLACE_COMPANY/$1/g" -e "s/$REPLACE_SPACEIP/$2/g" -e "s/$REPLACE_SYNAPSEIP/$3/g" $INF > $1
   cat $1 >> $FILE
   rm $1
}
```

Comment: This won't work if any of your strings to be replaced have characters that don't translate to themselves as regexes, or if your replacement strings contain `/`s.

Comment: See BashFAQ #21 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021 -- for more reliable alternatives.